# word 2010 add-in loaded but disabled on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I created a Word 2010 add-in with VS2010 C# on a Windows XP machine which is installed by an installer program.  Target CPU is x86.  The add-in simply has a button added to the ribbon bar, which, when clicked, adds some content to a document template.  Works fine on XP, but on Windows 7, the add-in is loaded but disabled.  Viewing add-ins from Word 2010 shows that it is loaded and checked, but it is still disabled. Registry settings are identical on XP and Windows 7.  Looking for suggestions!

Comment: Can you add a little more detail?

Comment: My hunch is that the setup program is the problem.  I will be rebuilding the solution on Windows7 as soon as VS2010 is installed, and re-test with the new build.

Comment: Well, no go with the re-build on Windows 7.  The deployment manifest for the add-in is not being generated (which should be the default), and so the installer won't build without it.  I think I'll scrap this idea entirely.  Thanks nonetheless for taking a look.